# AppleScript won't open Preferences… in Menubar

Tags: applescript, menubar

Unable to get this AppleScript to open Adguard Preferences. Weird thing after running script, if I open the menu and click on the button it instantly opens the Preferences instead of showing the drop down menu.

So it does seem to be clicking the Preferences menu item but isn’t following through on actually showing the Preferences window unless I mouse over and click on the button to select the Preferences option.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nKkD.png

Everything I've tried to adjust the code doesn't work.

```
    tell application "System Events"

    click menu item "Preferences…" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Adguard" of menu bar 1 of application process "Adguard"

    end tell
```

What should happen is the Preferences window opens on its own when running the script.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
tell application "System Events"
    click menu item 4 of menu 1 of menu bar item "Adguard" of menu bar 1 of application process "Adguard"
end tell
```